# How to Print Product Label copies 3-across on 3UP Label Paper?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

We need to print a product label (0.75x3.0") and copy it 3-across for 3UP label paper. The label paper looks like this (3x 0.75x3.0"):
[image]

Since we will regularly modify these labels to update LOT #s and expiry dates we need to minimize the possibility of error. Is it possible to put our label design in a layer and then triplicate it so our Illustrator document shows 3 copies of the design ready for printing?

This is the label design:

[image]

Comment: Yes use symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create an AI file of one label, if you make the art board the size of the finished label then this will make the next step easier...
- Create a second AI file (this will be your stepped file) and place the first file into this in the same way that you would place an image.
- Duplicate the placed file across the stepped file with the required spacing and number of copies.
- Print the stepped file.

Now, if you need to change the label, just change the individual (1 up) file and then update the links in the stepped file. Also, if you have multiple labels of the same size, then you can use the same stepped file and just link in the new labels.